# How Opensearch Serverless handle shards

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I'm currently working on AOSS (AWS OpenSearch Serverless) after working a while on Opensearch (OS)/ Elasticsearch (ES), and **I would like to understand how AOSS manage indices shards to be able to prevent errors, behaviours and else..**

So, does someone have an idea about it ?

On OS/ES we can handle shards by ourself, but as I understood on AOSS, it will be managed / modified on the fly.

Is there any way to know at what time it will be modified ? Is it related to the ingestion volume, duration, or is based on average usage ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Amazon OpenSearch serverless automatically handles your load and increase OCUs based on the load. If I talk of load yes OpenSearch serverless will handle apart from that you need to do everything from you end.  

Also, Let me know if My understanding varies from your query.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS OpenSearch Serverless, there are two categories of collections:

**1. Search Collection:**
In Search Collection, a consistent number of shards is maintained by default for every customer. This number is determined by dividing the total data account supports by the maximum size of each shard. Currently, the typical offering for Search Collection comprises 8 shards. If adjustments to this configuration are desired, users can contact AWS support for assistance.

**2. Time Series Collection:**
For Time Series Collection, the index begins with a relatively small number and dynamically increases based on incoming traffic and shard size. This adaptive approach allows for scalability in response to varying workloads.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).